# Load Image to picturebox control inside tabpage of tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform on which I have tab control and I'm adding a picture box control to the tab page. I want to load an image to this picturebox control in the tab page. I'm adding the control to tab page is as follows:

```
// initializing the picture box control
m_Canvas = new PhotoCanvas(); 
m_Canvas.BackColor = Color.White;
m_Canvas.Width = 500;
m_Canvas.Height = 400;
m_Canvas.Left = 0;
m_Canvas.Top = 0;

//adding the picture box control to tabpage
this.MainTab.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(m_Canvas);
```

I have tried to load the image using an `OpenFileDialog`:

```
m_Canvas.Image = new Bitmap(m_OpenFileDialog.FileName);
```

but it's not showing the loaded image Can anyone help me please?

From comments:

I'm using a button to load the image and the code inside it's click event is

```
private void Openbutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  m_OpenFileDialog.Title = "Select Image";
  if (m_OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {
    m_Canvas.Image = new Bitmap(m_OpenFileDialog.FileName);
    m_Canvas.Refresh();
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the actual error you are receiving?

Comment: it's not showing any error but i can't see the image or image is not loading

Comment: And have you choosed any image with your m_OpenFileDialog?

Comment: yes i showed like this

Comment: if (m_OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
              
            }

Comment: It's hard to say why the image does not get drawn without knowing what the class `PhotoCanvas` is, where it comes from and how it is implemented. Could you try to use an [PictureBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) directly?

Comment: i'm using a button to load the image and the code inside it's click event is  private void Openbutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            m_OpenFileDialog.Title = "Select Image";
            if (m_OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                m_Canvas.Image = new Bitmap(m_OpenFileDialog.FileName);
                m_Canvas.Refresh();
            }
        }

Comment: private void Openbutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            m_OpenFileDialog.Title = "Select Image";
            if (m_OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                m_Canvas.Image = new Bitmap(m_OpenFileDialog.FileName);
                m_Canvas.Refresh();
            }
        }

Comment: You are not using a picturebox?

Comment: i'm using a control which is inherited from picture box

Comment: have you tried simply hard-coding the path to the image and seeing if it displays properly? What kind of image is it?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string path = m_OpenFileDialog.FileName;
m_Canvas.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(path);
```